# Azure Mobile Engagement Resource Group Issue

Tags: azure-mobile-engagement

When I try to create an Azure Mobile Engagement, 
it always showed the following Resource Group warning.

I've tried US-Central and non-US-Central Resource Group and all of them have app in it, but still it shows warning.

is it my configuration issue? or there's something wrong with AME creation right now?

BTW, there's only "Use Existing" but no "Create New"?! Weird.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the support for that issue. 
Here is what they replied.

> Hello XXXX,
>
> Thank you for contacting Microsoft Support..................
>
> The following is the scope agreement for your incident:
>
> Issue Definition: You are unable to create an Azure Mobile Engagement
>   resource in any of your Resource Groups and getting the error "Invalid
>   resource group. Please use a specific group which already have app
>   collections."
>
> Scope Agreement: We can consider this case resolved when you can
>   successfully create an Azure Mobile Engagement resource
>
> Unfortunately this is a known issue at the moment. Our Product Group
>   are engaged to resolve this and I will update you as soon as I get
>   information from the Product Group.
>
> I apologize for the inconvenience.
>
> Best regards,

Comment: This issue probably won't get any fix in the coming months because Microsoft just announced the shut down of Azure Mobile Engagement https://azure.microsoft.com/fr-fr/services/mobile-engagement/

Comment: That's exactly what the customer service finally replied to me.

Comment: Sorry to hear that.. If you are looking for an Azure Mobile Engagement alternative, we at https://batch.com can help.

Answer (score 0):

These an option in VS 2017 when adding web application with .net for Azure mobile app. Maybe try it:
[image: Azure Mobile App]